# Create Separate Class to Print Smaller and Bigger of Random Array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, class

I am completely lost. I created a Data class that generates Arrays.

The Data class computes a set a of random numbers. I also made another class printing the sum of those numbers.

My issue is I want to try and add a third class to also print the smaller number and biggest. I just learned how to make the class for the sum but cannot figure out the Min and Max. Yes, I want to make a separate classes and not put the code in the MainClass.

```
package Pck1;

public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //create data object
        Data data = new Data(15, 101);
        //15 is the size and 101 is the range -- 101 including 0. so 100 is the max range
        data.displayData();

        Stats st = new Stats(data);
        st.calculateSum();
        System.out.println("sum = " + st.sum);
    }
}
```

```
package Pck1;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

public class Data {

        public int[] ary;
        public int size;
        // Default Constructor
        public Data() {
// Create an array with a default size 20
            size = 20;
            ary =new int[size];
        }
        // Modified Constructor
        public Data(int size, int range) {
            this.size = size;
            ary = new int[size];
            storeRandomData(range);
        }
        // Store random data in the array
        public void storeRandomData(int range) {
            Random rndGen = new Random(-1);
            for (int i = 0; i < ary.length; i++) {
                ary[i] = rndGen.nextInt(101);
            }
        }
        // Display the data stored in the array
        public void displayData() {
            String buffer = Arrays.toString(ary);
            System.out.println(buffer);
        }

}
/** Look for the numbers, create a method in data that
 * figures out the smaller number -- create another method that finds the biggest number
 * print out all number and min/max.
 */
```

```
package Pck1;

public class Stats {
    public Data data;
    public int sum;
    public Stats() {
    }
    public Stats(Data data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
    public int calculateSum() {
        int[] ary = data.ary;
        sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < ary.length; i++) {
            sum += ary[i];
        }
        return sum;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get min and max in their own methods by looping the array and always updating them when a greater/smaller value is found:

```
public class MinMax {
    protected Data data;
    protected int min;
    protected int max;
    public MinMax(Data data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
    public int getMin() {
        int[] ary = data.ary;
        if (ary.length == 0) return min = 0; //some default if the array is empty
        min = ary[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < ary.length; i++) {
            if (min > ary[i]) min = ary[i];
        }
        return min;
    }

    public int getMax() {
        int[] ary = data.ary;
        if (ary.length == 0) return min = 0; //some default if the array is empty
        max = ary[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < ary.length; i++) {
            if (max < ary[i]) max = ary[i];
        }
        return max;
    }
}
```

Comment: When I implement this code and run it, I get zeroes for min and max. Added to MainClass: MinMax minmax = new MinMax(data);
        System.out.println("min = " + minmax.min);
        System.out.println("max = " + minmax.max);

Comment: @darth.vater `getMin()` is responsible to compute `min` and `getMax()` is responsible to compute `max`. You missed calling `getMin()` and `getMax`, hence the values are not computed and you get the default values instead.